# how to removing partly duplicates from tweets list in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I am new in python and I am carrying out a sentiment analysis but somehow i have to remove duplicates tweets. the problem is that i want to remove every tweet that began with the same first 5 words using like this function :

```
f1 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\pp.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open(r'C:\oo.csv', 'wb'))
tweet = set()
for row in f1:
    if row[1] not in tweet:
        writer.writerow(row)
        tweet.add( row[1] )
        f1.close()
        writer.close()
```

Comment: First of all, don't close f1 and writer in the for loop. Leave them open until you're done all the iterations. Second of all, what's the actual result your getting and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: Are the tweets sorted or in random order? Can the entire file be held in memory?

Comment: The mean problem is how to use regular expression to remove the duplicates of tweets that have the same starts like this two tweets:@tesco's dave lewis is playing tough and facing up to the reality of ‰£6.38bn losses: you can't m... URL marketing in
@tesco's dave lewis is playing tough and facing up to the reality of ‰£6.38bn losses: you can't make an... URL digital

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do to set this up:

```
f1 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\pp.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open(r'C:\oo.csv', 'wb'))
tweet = set()
index = 5
for row in f1:
    if row[1][:index] not in tweet:
        writer.writerow(row)
        tweet.add( row[1][:index] )
f1.close()
writer.close()
```

Basically index is telling your code to only read 5 characters into the start of the string and then it stores only that many characters to check back on later. You could set it to whatever number you want, so if you want it checking 40 characters just adjust the index.

There wont be an index error, because a string that's too short will just read the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

```
f1 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\pp.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open(r'C:\oo.csv', 'wb'))

tweet = set()
tweet_start = set()
for row in f1:
    the_tweet = row[1]
    start = ' '.join(the_tweet.split(' ')[:5])
    if start not in tweet_start:
        writer.writerow(row)
        tweet.add(the_tweet)
        tweet_start.add(start)
f1.close()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Tesco Announced A Record Loss Of å£6.4 Billion So yueki89wks,s;
Tesco Announced A Record Loss Of å£6.4 Billion So jjjuuopytttt

Comment: these are examples of the duplicates